# Probability Distributions and Expected Values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm really at a road-block with the following question.

> Water from a farm dam is used according to a normal distribution with
>   mean $10$L and variance $2$L$^2$. The number of people sourcing water from
>   the dam follows a Poisson distribution with a mean of $8$.
>
> Show that the average amount of water used is $80L$.

All I have in the way of working so far is the assignment of random variables. Namely,

Let $X \sim N(10,2)$ and $Y\sim Pois(8)$.

Beyond here I'm stuck.

Comment: This is a random sum of random variables. Generating functions usually help with these. Also the variance should have units litres squared!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you should calculate 
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}\cdot k}{k!}\cdot \mu$$

assuming $$\lambda=8,\mu=10$$ Technically, it is $E(X) E(Y)=\mu\lambda$.

Comment: Did you determine $S = ...$ using the law total expectation?
Namely, $E(\text{Water Usage})$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} E(\text{Water Usage}|\text{Number of People} = k)\cdot Pr(\text{Number of People} = k)$?

Comment: Yes, but when you condition on $k$ you should also multiply it by $k$. Inside the sum is $k$ times the expectation conditioned on $k$, multiplied by the probability of $k$.